# Changing Router IP Address/Default Gateway

Tags: routing

I am upgrading our MPLS Circuits for our HQ and all remote sites. During the Switch over, I will need to run both routers simultaneously. How can I set up two default gateways? Is this a possibility? Let me know your thoughts and/or comments.

Thank you,
Brian Ingram

Answer (score 2):

Don't set up two default gateways. During the deployment process, when the new router is ready to handle traffic, move the default gateway IP address from the old router to the new router. Then decommission the old router.

Comment: David, The issue with that is, it will take several days to convert all of my remote locations from the old MPLS to the New MPLS, and I was hoping to run both simultaneously during the conversion process. I may not be able to to, but I was hoping to find a way. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should be able to run both simultaneously during the conversion process. As soon as the routers have at least one LAN in common and are sharing routing tables, either one should work fine as the default gateway for any network it's connected to. If a packet goes to the "wrong" router, it should just forward it to the other over the common LAN. You can also use a dedicated link between the two routers (if you have a spare Ethernet port) and just use that dedicated link for traffic that gets to the "wrong" router.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what brand of equipment you are using, but have you considered setting up a router redundancy protocol such as HSRP, or VRRP? Here is a link on the subject. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/ensure-cisco-router-redundancy-with-hsrp/6063344